# asp.net webservices - how to return parameter on the same level as "d"

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

Since .NET 3.5, web services that return json wrap the data in a parameter named "d".  The feature I'm describing has been documented [here](http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/) among other places.

I'm wondering if there is a way to add a parameter to the json that would be on the same level as "d".

So borrowing from the example above, if the output of one of my web services is

```
{"d":{"__type"    : "Person",
      "FirstName" : "Dave",
      "LastName"  : "Ward"}}
```

What I would like it to be is

```
{"d":{"__type"    : "Person",
      "FirstName" : "Dave",
      "LastName"  : "Ward"},
 "z":{"__type"    : "AnotherType",
      "Property"  : "Value"}}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not recommended in any way. JSON results are wrapped as a security feature.

However if you ever ABSOLUTELY NEED to, here is a solution:

In the `[WebMethod]` that you need to alter the elements add

```
        Context.Response.ClearContent();
        Context.Response.Filter = new JsonHackFilter(Context.Response.Filter);
```

Where `JsonHackFilter` is

```
class JsonHackFilter : MemoryStream
{
    private readonly Stream _outputStream = null;

    public JsonHackFilter(Stream output)
    {
        _outputStream = output;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {

        string bufferContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        // TODO: Manually manipulate the string here

        _outputStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bufferContent), offset,
                           Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(bufferContent));

        base.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a way.  The web service function is returning an object type.  Even if you try to have it return Object() is will do is {"d":[Object 1..., Object 2...]}

If you do need that specific Output format you would write a Generic Handler instead and have the ashx page return the json in the specific format that you want.